# Is there a way I can get a Windows 7 Phone  UI on my Android device?

Tags: user-interface, windows-mobile

Is there an App/Widget/Custom Rom that gives you a Windows 7 Phone-like User Interface?

Of course I don't need the Microsoft-specific stuff such as XBox Live, etc.
But instead of app icons for phone/msg/settings/etc, you have the nice big ... windows... that you can slide around instead.

I hope its not too subjective. Basically I want the Windows 7 UI on my Android phone (even just in the home screen).

Comment: I don't know of anything like this.  It's almost definitely phone-specific as well -- I wouldn't expect a custom UI developed for a Droid to work on a Galaxy S, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an alternative launcher that purports to give the look-and-feel of Windows Phone 7. I can't imagine it's more than "skin-deep", however.

Some information (and a video) here: http://phandroid.com/2010/12/09/turn-your-android-phone-into-a-windows-phone-7-with-this-metro-ui-launcher/

Comment: Ah yea, so there is something out there. Thanks. It looks like it could use more work. Also I don't think it's worth the $3.